# I am making a discord bot that sends new uploaded books an I get this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

The problem is taht when i use `!firsttime` command I get the error saying

```
Ignoring exception in command firsttime:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "goodreads.py", line 27, in firsttime_command
    for link in links.reverse():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception

Here is the code

```
import re
import json
import aiohttp
from datetime import datetime

import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

JSON_PATH = "json file path"
REGEX = "<a class=readable bookTitle href=(.*)[?].*>"
URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/genres/new_releases/fantasy"
CHANNEL_ID = 834867425677803580

class Goodreads(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    self.check_website.start()

  @commands.command(name="firsttime")
  async def firsttime_command(self, ctx):
    links = await self.make_request()
    data = {}
    now = str(datetime.utcnow())
    for link in links.reverse():
      data[link] = now
    with open(JSON_PATH, "w") as f:
      json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

  @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
  async def check_website(self):
    links = await self.make_request()

with open(JSON_PATH, "r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for link in links:
  if link not in data.keys():
    await self.bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).send(f"A new fantasy book released.\n{link}")
    data[link] = str(datetime.utcnow())
    with open(JSON_PATH, "w") as f:
      json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

  async def make_request(self):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
      async with ses.get(URL) as res:
        text = await res.text()
        text = text.replace("\\\"", "")
        return re.findall(REGEX, text)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.add_cog(Goodreads(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
  print("Connected")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Ready")

bot.run("tokens")
```

Comment: It says: `The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception`, what is the following exception?

Comment: I think I saw this code in other question. Did you repeate it? It seems you still didn't learn how to debug code - even with `print()`.  If code shows you in which line you have error then first you could use `print()` to check values in variables - it seems you get `None` in `links` and you runs `links.reverse()` which means `None.reverse()`. you should skipt all code when you get `None`.

Comment: If you get `links` from ` self.make_request()` then you should check in `make_request()` what you get in variable - maybe you use wrong value or on some pages `findall(REGEX, ...)` can't find elements and it give `None`. And again you could use `pritn()` to debug it - check what you get in HTML from server. Maybe it send different HTML then you expect - ie. it may send error message, warning for bots or ReCaptch, etc. So shortly you have to debug code - and check all what you have in variable - don't trust code.

Comment: did you test your Regex before ? It is wrong. I checked HTML on page and there is no `class=readable bookTitle` but `class=\"readable bookTitle\"` and `href=\"...\"` instead of `href=...`. BTW: and you have to remeber that `aiohttp` can get HTML but it can't run `JavaScript` - so if you check HTML manually in browser then first turn off `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in code and using `print()` to check values in variables I found that all problem is

```
.reverse()
```

which works `in-place` - so it changes order in original list and it returns `None`

You have to do

```
 links.reverse()

 for link in links:
     #... code ...
```

or you shoud use `reversed()`

```
 for link in reversed(links):
     #... code ...
```

or you can use `slice` for this

```
 for link in links[::-1]:
     #... code ...
```

---

**BTW:** the same is with `list.sort()` and `sorted(list)`